# Check if one value exists in any rows of any columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any function to check if a value exists in any rows of any columns in pandas, such as

```
columnA columnB columnC
"john" 3 True
"mike" 1 False
"bob" 0 False
```

on the dataframe above, I want to know if there are any values named `"mike"` in any elements of the whole dataframe, and if it exists, I'd like to get `True` - otherwise get `False`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Something like this:

```
df.apply(lambda x: 'mike' in x.values, axis=1).any()
```

or

```
df.applymap(lambda x: x == 'mike').any().any()
```

Comment: The latter is substantially faster. df.applymap(lambda x: x == 'mike').any().any() took under 4 seconds on 283900 rows × 30 columns while df.apply(lambda x: 'mike' in x.values, axis=1).any() took over 7 minutes.