# How to determine whether a Pandas Column contains a particular value

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to determine whether there is an entry in a Pandas column that has a particular value. I tried to do this with `if x in df['id']`. I thought this was working, except when I fed it a value that I knew was not in the column `43 in df['id']` it still returned `True`. When I subset to a data frame only containing entries matching the missing id `df[df['id'] == 43]` there are, obviously, no entries in it. How to I determine if a column in a Pandas data frame contains a particular value and why doesn't my current method work? (FYI, I have the same problem when I use the implementation in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19630449/2327821) to a similar question).

Answer (score 359, accepted):

`in` of a Series checks whether the value is in the index:

```
In [11]: s = pd.Series(list('abc'))

In [12]: s
Out[12]: 
0    a
1    b
2    c
dtype: object

In [13]: 1 in s
Out[13]: True

In [14]: 'a' in s
Out[14]: False
```

One option is to see if it's in [unique](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html) values:

```
In [21]: s.unique()
Out[21]: array(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype=object)

In [22]: 'a' in s.unique()
Out[22]: True
```

or a python set:

```
In [23]: set(s)
Out[23]: {'a', 'b', 'c'}

In [24]: 'a' in set(s)
Out[24]: True
```

As pointed out by @DSM, it may be more efficient (especially if you're just doing this for one value) to just use in directly on the values:

```
In [31]: s.values
Out[31]: array(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype=object)

In [32]: 'a' in s.values
Out[32]: True
```

Comment: I don't want to know whether it is unique necessarily, mainly I want to know if it's there.

Comment: I think `'a' in s.values` should be faster for long Series.

Comment: @AndyHayden Do you know why, for `'a' in s`, pandas chooses to check the index rather than the values of the series? In dictionaries they check keys, but a pandas series should behave more like a list or array, no?

Comment: @LeiHuang a Series is a key-value datastructure (I guess so is a DataFrame which acts the same here), also the `in` can be _very_ efficient on an Index, it's `O(1)`, whereas on an array it'll be `O(n)`. But you're right this is something that you do find oneself doing occasionally... my claim is generally there's a better way/alternative...

Comment: Starting from pandas 0.24.0 , using `s.values` and `df.values` is highly discoraged. See [this](https://pandas-dev.github.io/pandas-blog/pandas-extension-arrays.html). Also, `s.values` is actually much slower in some cases.

Comment: @QusaiAlothman neither `.to_numpy` or `.array` are available on a Series, so I'm not entirely sure what alternative they're advocating (I don't read "highly discouraged"). In fact they're saying that .values may not return a numpy array, e.g. in the case of a categorical... but that's fine as `in` will still work as expected (indeed more efficiently that it's numpy array counterpart)

Comment: Adding to the comment of @QusaiAlothman : Use ``"a" in s.series``!

Comment: this works for me. You can perform this on a dataframe column by executing:  ``"a" in df["column_name"].values``

Comment: Since the question is whether  a column (not the index) contains a value and using the `.values` property is the most efficient way to do that, using that property should appear first in this answer.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work for the case `np.nan in s.values`. `s` may contain `np.nan` and will still return `False`.

Answer (score 64):

You can try this to check a particular value 'x' in a particular column named 'id'

```
if x in df['id'].values
```

Comment: I dont know why this has only 9 upvotes...does it have some implications regarding speed etc...?

Answer (score 59):

You can also use [pandas.Series.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) although it's a little bit longer than `'a' in s.values`:

```
In [2]: s = pd.Series(list('abc'))

In [3]: s
Out[3]: 
0    a
1    b
2    c
dtype: object

In [3]: s.isin(['a'])
Out[3]: 
0    True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool

In [4]: s[s.isin(['a'])].empty
Out[4]: False

In [5]: s[s.isin(['z'])].empty
Out[5]: True
```

But this approach can be more flexible if you need to match multiple values at once for a DataFrame (see [DataFrame.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html))

```
>>> df = DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [1, 4, 7]})
>>> df.isin({'A': [1, 3], 'B': [4, 7, 12]})
       A      B
0   True  False  # Note that B didn't match 1 here.
1  False   True
2   True   True
```

Comment: You could also use the [DataFrame.any()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) function: `s.isin(['a']).any()`

Answer (score 49):

```
found = df[df['Column'].str.contains('Text_to_search')]
print(found.count())
```

the `found.count()` will contains number of matches

And if it is 0 then means string was not found in the Column.

Comment: worked for me, but I used len(found) to get the count

Comment: Yes len(found) is a somewhat better option.

Comment: This approach worked for me but I had to include the parameters `na=False` and `regex=False` for my use case, as explained here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html

Comment: But string.contains does a substring search. Ex: If a value called "head_hunter" is present. Passing "head" in str.contains matches and gives True which is wrong.

Comment: @karthikeyan Its not wrong. Depends on the context of your search. What if you are search for addresses or product. You'll need all product that fit description.

Answer (score 34):

I did a few simple tests:

```
In [10]: x = pd.Series(range(1000000))

In [13]: timeit 999999 in x.values
567 µs ± 25.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [24]: timeit 9 in x.values
666 µs ± 15.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [16]: timeit (x == 999999).any()
6.86 ms ± 107 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [21]: timeit x.eq(999999).any()
7.03 ms ± 33.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [22]: timeit x.eq(9).any()
7.04 ms ± 60 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [15]: timeit x.isin([999999]).any()
9.54 ms ± 291 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [17]: timeit 999999 in set(x)
79.8 ms ± 1.98 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Interestingly it doesn't matter if you look up 9 or 999999, it seems like it takes about the same amount of time using the `in` syntax (must be using some vectorized computation)

```
In [24]: timeit 9 in x.values
666 µs ± 15.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [25]: timeit 9999 in x.values
647 µs ± 5.21 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [26]: timeit 999999 in x.values
642 µs ± 2.11 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [27]: timeit 99199 in x.values
644 µs ± 5.31 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [28]: timeit 1 in x.values
667 µs ± 20.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Seems like using x.values is the fastest, but maybe there is a more elegant way in pandas?

Comment: It would be great if you change order of results from smallest to largest. Nice work!

Comment: Regarding there not being any big difference between checking if 9 or 999999 is `in x.values`, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53424069/17219897). Apparently the `in` syntax is pretty much equivalent to `(elem == x.values).any()`.

Answer (score 11):

Or use `Series.tolist` or `Series.any`:

```
>>> s = pd.Series(list('abc'))
>>> s
0    a
1    b
2    c
dtype: object
>>> 'a' in s.tolist()
True
>>> (s=='a').any()
True
```

`Series.tolist` makes a list about of a `Series`, and the other one i am just getting a boolean `Series` from a regular `Series`, then checking if there are any `True`s in the boolean `Series`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`query()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) to find the rows where the condition holds and get the number of rows with [`shape[0]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shape.html). If there exists at least one entry, this statement is `True`:

```
df.query('id == 123').shape[0] > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple condition:

```
if any(str(elem) in ['a','b'] for elem in df['column'].tolist()):
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
df[df['id']==x].index.tolist()
```

If `x` is present in `id` then it'll return the list of indices where it is present, else it gives an empty list.

Answer (score 2):

I had a CSV file to read:

```
df = pd.read_csv('50_states.csv')
```

And after trying:

```
if value in df.column:
    print(True)
```

which never printed true, even though the value was in the column;

I tried:

```
for values in df.column:
    if value == values:
        print(True)
        #Or do something
    else:
        print(False)
```

Which worked. I hope this can help!

Comment: The reason why this doesn't work.. df.columns is a list of your column names, what you can do is df['column'] == "value", which provides a boolean series. You can then add that inside a df[ ] call to return the rows which the boolean was True. df[df["column"] == "value"].

Comment: @Jenobi Would you be able to elaborate or post this solution with your addition as I'm struggling to implement it

Comment: @Will Jordan 
```data = [{'name': "jenobi", "foo": "bar"}, {'name': "jenobi", "foo": "baz"}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,)
_filter = df['foo'] == 'bar'
df[_filter]```
returns all the rows which match your filter. you can also merge the second to last and last lines such as df[df['foo'] == 'bar'], as this includes a boolean filter from before.