# Type Conversion in python AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'astype'

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion

I am confused by the type conversion in python pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['1.23', '0.123']})
type(df['a'])
df['a'].astype(float)
```

Here `df` is a pandas series and its contents are 2 strings, then I can apply `astype(float)` on this pandas series, and it correctly convert all string into float. However

```
df['a'][1].astype(float)
```

gives me AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'astype'. My question is: how can that be? I could convert the whole series from string to float but I couldn't convert the entry of this series from string to float?

Also, I load my raw data set

```
df['id'].astype(int)
```

it generates  ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
This one seems to suggest that there is a blank in my `df['id']`. So I check whether it is true by typing

```
'' in df['id']
```

it says false. So I am very confused.

Comment: You have to use like this df['a'].iloc[1].astype(float), it will not throw error

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`df['a']` returns a `Series` object that has `astype` as a vectorized way to convert all elements in the series into another one.

`df['a'][1]` returns the content of one cell of the dataframe, in this case the string `'0.123'`. This is now returning a `str` object that doesn't have this function. To convert it use regular python instruction:

```
type(df['a'][1])
Out[25]: str

float(df['a'][1])
Out[26]: 0.123

type(float(df['a'][1]))
Out[27]: float
```

As per your second question, the operator `in` that is at the end calling `__contains__` against the series with `''` as argument, here is the docstring of the operator:

```
help(pd.Series.__contains__)
Help on function __contains__ in module pandas.core.generic:

__contains__(self, key)
    True if the key is in the info axis
```

It means that the `in` operator is searching your empty string in the index, not the contents of it.

The way to search your empty strings is to use the equal operator:

```
df
Out[54]: 
    a
0  42
1    

'' in df
Out[55]: False

df==''
Out[56]: 
       a
0  False
1   True

df[df['a']=='']
Out[57]: 
  a
1
```

Comment: thanks!  I have a short followup question. So in your example `df`, if I want to check whether number 42 is in the df, I should not use `42 in df` or `42 in df['a']` or `42 in df[['a']]` right? the `in` is checking the index of a pandas series? but what about  `df[['a']]`? it is a pandas dataframe. So `in` when operating on a dataframe is still checking the index?

Comment: Same mechanics for a dataframe. So do df==42

Answer (score 2):

`df['a'][1]` will return the actual value inside the array, at the position `1`, which is in fact a string. You can convert it by using `float(df['a'][1])`.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['1.23', '0.123']})
>>> type(df['a'])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
>>> df['a'].astype(float)
0    1.230
1    0.123
Name: a, dtype: float64
>>> type(df['a'][1])
<type 'str'>
```

For the second question, maybe you have an empty value on your raw data. The correct test would be:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['1', '']})
>>> '' in df['a'].values
True
```

Source for the second question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21320011/5335508

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the solutions already posted you could also simply use:

```
df['a'].astype(float)[1]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
data1 = {'age': [1,1,2, np.nan],
        'gender': ['m', 'f', 'm', np.nan],
        'salary': [2,1,2, np.nan]}

x = pd.DataFrame(data1)
for i in list(x.columns):
    print(type((x[i].iloc[1])))
    if isinstance(x[i].iloc[1], str):
        print("It is String")
    else:
        print('Not a String')
```

Comment: Posting code without any explanation isn't welcome here. Please edit your post.