# Pandas dataframe check if string is not in column to append

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with one of the columns called artist. I would like to append a new row only if the new artist name is not in this column.

I tried but with no success:

```
if (all_data != name.all(axis = 0)):
        all_data = all_data.append({'artist':str(name), 'netWorth':str(worth.strip())}, ignore_index = True)
```

This is all the code I have:

```
def get_webpage(i, url):
    URL = url+str(i)
    response = requests.get(URL)
    return bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

COLUMNS = ['artist', 'netWorth']
all_data = pd.DataFrame(columns = COLUMNS)

def scrape(soup):
    artists = soup.find_all('article', class_ = 'thumb-wrap')
    for ar in artists:
        name = ar.h3.a.text
        worth = ar.div.find('div', class_='bc-networth').text
        global all_data 
        if (all_data['artist'] != name).any():
            all_data = all_data.append({'artist':str(name), 'netWorth':str(worth.strip())}, ignore_index = True)

i = 1
url = 'http://www.therichest.com/celebnetworth-category/celeb/singer/page/'
while (i<=14):
    soup = get_webpage(i, url)
    i = i+1
    data = scrape(soup)
i = 1
url = 'http://www.therichest.com/celebnetworth-category/celeb/musician/page/'
while (i<=7):
    soup = get_webpage(i, url)
    i = i+1
    data = scrape(soup)
```

Comment: can you show some sample input and output?

Comment: Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319929/how-to-determine-whether-a-pandas-column-contains-a-particular-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need check one column `artist` only:

```
if (all_data['artist'] != str(name)).all():
```

**Sample**:

```
all_data = pd.DataFrame({'netWorth':[5,3],
                        'artist':list('ab')})

print (all_data)
   netWorth artist
0         5      a
1         3      b

name = 'a'
b = 10

if (all_data['artist'] != str(name)).all():
    all_data = all_data.append({'artist':str(name), 'netWorth':b }, ignore_index = True)

print (all_data)
   netWorth artist
0         5      a
1         3      b
```

```
name = 'd'
b = 10

if (all_data['artist'] != name).all():
    all_data = all_data.append({'artist':str(name), 'netWorth':b }, ignore_index = True)

print (all_data)
   netWorth artist
0         5      a
1         3      b
2        10      d
```

Comment: @user9737581 - Glad can help! Please dont forget accept solution if helpful. Thanks.