# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "numpy.int64") to str

Tags: python, nlp

I want to print the variable based on the index number based on the following dataset:

[image]

Here I used the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

airline = pd.read_csv("AIR-LINE.csv")

pnr = input("Enter the PNR Number ")
index = airline.PNRNum[airline.PNRNum==pnr].index.tolist()
zzz = int(index[0])
print( "The flight number is " + airline.FlightNo[zzz]  )
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "numpy.int64") to str

I know that the error is because the `FlightNo` variable contains `int` value. But I don't know how to solve it. Any idea?

Comment: `print( "The flight number is " + str(airline.FlightNo[zzz])  )`?

Comment: Your'e a legend!! Works fine. Thanks mate!!

Comment: BTW can you tell why is it like that?

Comment: Check my answer. @PrakashNatarajan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only want to print, then do this:

```
print("The flight number is ", airline.FlightNo[zzz])
```

There is no need to convert the `int` to `str` here. You get an error in your statement because you can't concatenate a string and an integer. Try doing `"a" + 1` in Python console and see what error it shows.

Comment: No it throws the same error. Should use `str(airline.FlightNo[zzz]`.

Comment: Did you replace `+` by `,`? @PrakashNatarajan

Comment: You can't concatenate different data-type objects. Both objects need to be of the type `str`. But when you print using a `,`, it automatically formats the integer. Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your issue. @PrakashNatarajan

Comment: Also i want to seperate the wrongly entered `PNRNum` during the input of the PNR Number. I used `if airline.PNRNum!=pnr:
 print("Enter correct PNR Number.")` But it throws error. How could I check if the entered value is not present in the specific column?

Comment: @PrakashNatarajan See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319929/how-to-determine-whether-a-pandas-column-contains-a-particular-value).

Comment: Thanks mate!! That's exactly what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

convert your int to a string:

```
str(airline.Flightno[zzz])
```