# To get the True row if I have both True & False rows for the same Item using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

**I have a dataframe with this data.**

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Item':['2', '1', '2'],
    'IsAvailable':['True', 'False', 'False']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
================================

Item  |  IsAvailable
---------------------
  2   |     True
  1   |     False
  2   |     False
```

In the dataframe, I have data like above shown. As you can see I have both True as well as False for Item 2. In that case I want to have a single record with just True.

**Expected output:**

```
Item  |  IsAvailable
---------------------
  2   |     True
  1   |     False
```

Please help in writing the condition for this using python pandas.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since bool is also kind of int:

```
df = df.sort_values('IsAvailable').drop_duplicates(subset=['Item'], keep='last')
```

This will reorder your items though, of course. Funny thing: it works even when you have True/False strings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need first replace strings `True` and `False` to boolean if necessary and then get first row with `True` per groups by [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for indices and selecting by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df['IsAvailable'] = df['IsAvailable'].map({'True':True, 'False':False})

df = df.loc[df.groupby('Item', sort=False)['IsAvailable'].idxmax()]
print (df)
  Item  IsAvailable
0    2         True
1    1        False
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the first occurence:
**Edit:** as per @jezrael, you may want to map your strings to booleans first

```
df['IsAvailable'] = df['IsAvailable'].replace({'True':True, 'False':False})
dfOut = df.drop_duplicates(subset="Item", keep='first')
print(dfOut)

  Item IsAvailable
0    2        True
1    1       False
```

Comment: It not test `True` and `False`, working because sample data only.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution where we check if the value True is one of the values assigned to each item.  If so, the outcome is also True.

```
>>> df.groupby(['Item'])['IsAvailable'].apply(lambda x: 'True' in set(x))
Item
1    False
2     True
Name: IsAvailable, dtype: bool
```

If you want to keep the column name, use

```
>>> df.groupby(['Item'])['IsAvailable'].apply(lambda x: 'True' in set(x)).reset_index()
  Item  IsAvailable
0    1        False
1    2         True
```

Comment: Your previous code works i.e, with any(x)... true in x is giving me the wrong output.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that as well.  any(x) gave true as long as there was some value in the list that x is.  Perhaps it is interpreting 'False' as string, and bool('False') is True in python.  But the current version works, (lambda x: True in x).

Comment: The output is not as per my request. Please check once the expected output.

Comment: I'm sorry you're right.  My mistake is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21320011/8446061. See updated answer.