# Search certain values in a column of a dataframe when it matches values of a list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following list:

```
a = [1, 1193, 1219, 1210, 2115, 1198, 1197, 1196, 1136, 3793]
```

I also have a Dataframe with 8570 rows × 4 columns.

Now I want to have all the values of the 2nd column of the dataframe when a value of my list 'a' matches with a value of the first column of the dataframe. How can I do this in python (numpy/pandas)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine whether a Pandas Column contains a particular value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319929/how-to-determine-whether-a-pandas-column-contains-a-particular-value)

Comment: For each value use de python command 'in'.
Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319929/how-to-determine-whether-a-pandas-column-contains-a-particular-value).

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`np.isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1000, 2000, size=(1000,4)))
a = np.array([1, 1193, 1219, 1210, 2115, 1198, 1197, 1196, 1136, 3793])
a[np.isin(a, df.iloc[:,1])]
```

Output:

```
array([1219, 1198, 1197, 1196, 1136])
```