# Why are items in a pandas column, not in the pandas column that they're in?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

If I have a dataframe of random values:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10, size=[5, 5]))
```

and I choose any column and run the following code:

```
for x in df[0]:
    print(x in df[0])
```

I would expect the output to be:

```
True
True
True
True
True
```

but it isn't. It prints an assortment of "True" and "False". It seems to be printing "True" for items in range(5) and False otherwise. I tried changing my dataframe to:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10, size=[6, 6]))
```

and the same code prints True for elements in range(6). If I change the condition to:

```
for x in df[0]:
    print(x in list(df[0]))
```

It prints all True as expected (regardless of the size of the dataframe). Can anyone explain why this is?

Comment: It is checking that the item is in the index. There is a good explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319929/how-to-determine-whether-a-pandas-column-contains-a-particular-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df[0]` is a pandas series object `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`. Now, `x in df[0]` which checks for item existence in **series**, checks existence of `x` in the **index**.

example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(25).reshape(5,5))
#    0   1   2   3   4
#0   0   1   2   3   4
#1   5   6   7   8   9
#2  10  11  12  13  14
#3  15  16  17  18  19
#4  20  21  22  23  24

print(10 in df[0])
#False
```

However, `list(df[0])` returns a list of pandas series values (similarly, `df[0].values`, `df[0].to_numpy()`, `set(df[0])` are all values) and `x in list(df[0])` checks existence of `x` in the **values**.

```
print(10 in list(df[0]))
#True
print(10 in set(df[0]))
#True
print(10 in df[0].values)
#True
print(10 in df[0].to_numpy())
#True
```