# return a list if the column contains a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I would like to check if the `Names` column contains any of the strings in the `kw`. If yes, return the list.

Here is the data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Names':['APPLE JUICE','APPLE DRINK','APPLE JUICE DRINK', 'APPLE','ORANGE AVAILABLE','TEA AVAILABLE']})
kw = ['APPLE JUICE', 'DRINK', 'ORANGE', 'LEMONS', 'STRAWBERRY', 'BLUEBERRY', 'TEA COFFEE']
```

I've tried:

```
df['Names2'] = df['Names'].apply(lambda x: [k if any([k in x for k in kw]) else ''])
```

But it returns:

```
    Names   Names2
0   APPLE JUICE [<function <lambda> at 0x0000017BB875C550>]
1   APPLE DRINK [<function <lambda> at 0x0000017BB875C550>]
2   APPLE JUICE DRINK   [<function <lambda> at 0x0000017BB875C550>]
3   APPLE   []
4   ORANGE AVAILABLE    [<function <lambda> at 0x0000017BB875C550>]
5   TEA AVAILABLE   []
```

I am expecting an output like:

```
    Names   Names2
0   APPLE JUICE ['APPLE JUICE']
1   APPLE DRINK ['DRINK']
2   APPLE JUICE DRINK   ['APPLE JUICE', 'DRINK']
3   APPLE   []
4   ORANGE AVAILABLE    ['ORANGE']
5   TEA AVAILABLE   []
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine whether a Pandas Column contains a particular value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319929/how-to-determine-whether-a-pandas-column-contains-a-particular-value)

Comment: thanks! I tried PieCot's answer, and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close:

```py
df['Names2'] = df['Names'].map(lambda x: [y for y in kw if y in x])
```