# Check if value is in Pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've having an issue checking is a value is in the following dataframe:

| index | open | high | SignalEMA25M50M | PositionEMA25M50M |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-30 05:35:00 | 0.000059 | 0.000059 | 0 | -1.0 |
| 2021-03-30 05:40:00 | 0.000059 | 0.000059 | 0 | 0.0 |
| 2021-03-30 05:45:00 | 0.000059 | 0.000059 | 0 | 0.0 |

i am trying to simply return true if the PositionEMA25M50M contains -1.0

i have tried:

```
if -1.0 in indicator_5min_df.PositionEMA25M50M:
    print('true')
else:
    print('false')
```

however this returns false every time... i assume this is something to do with PositionEMA25M50M being of type float64 however i've also tried

```
if np.float64(-1.0) in indicator_5min_df.PositionEMA25M50M:
    print('true')
else:
    print('false')
```

which has given me the same result...

any ideas how i can fix this?

Comment: @jezrael Wrong dupe. OP wants to return `True` as well. Please attach a proper dupe or open the question.

Comment: @MayankPorwal - yop, I add another dupe too.

Comment: First dupe explain `in` why not working, second using `any` or `all` for test.

Comment: No. That is wrong. This way you can close all questions that are asked.

Comment: hmmm, so if you think only second dupe matching, first be free remove.

Comment: No dupe is completely matching.

Comment: I think you need to open the question.

Comment: Ok, explanation `No dupe is completely matching` is not very clear.

Comment: I think correct dupe is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319929/how-to-determine-whether-a-pandas-column-contains-a-particular-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `if` loop. You can directly use `Series.eq` with `any` to check if any row has `-1` for this column:

```
In [990]: df['PositionEMA25M50M'].eq(-1).any()
Out[990]: True
```

Comment: dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319929/how-to-determine-whether-a-pandas-column-contains-a-particular-value