# relational reference in pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

Exploratory question: if I have a dataframe `A` with a column `Person_Id`, and each row in `Person_Id` is a `person_id`, and I have another dataframe `B` where the index is `Person_Id`, and the columns are info related to that `person_id`, is there a nice way to quickly reference dataframe `B` when I access `Person_Id` dataframe `A`?

Comment: see [pandas-merging-101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: No, you have to merge your dataframes. Dataframes are not a relational database.

Comment: Without using any of the merge functions

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40429755/14289892 or [remap-values-in-pandas-column-with-a-dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250771/remap-values-in-pandas-column-with-a-dict)

Comment: Why don't you want to use `merge`? Is this homework?