# Python: IF statement on the index of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

Working through my first project in pandas and trying to build a simple program that retrieves the ID's and information from a large CSV.

I'm able to get it working when I print it. However when I try to make it a conditional statement it won't work. Is this because of the way I set the index?

The intent is to input an ID and in return list out all the rows with this ID in the CSV.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd  

file = PartIdsWithVehicleData.csv

excel = pd.read_csv(file, index_col = "ID", dtype={'ID': "str"})

UserInput = input("Enter a part number: ")
result = (excel.loc[UserInput]) 

#If I print this.... it will work
print(result)

#however when I try to make it a conditional statement it runs my else clause. 

if UserInput in excel:
    print(result)
else:
    print("Part number is not in file.")

#one thing I did notice is that if I find the boolean value of the part number (index) it says false..

print(UserInput in excel)
```

Comment: So... What are you asking is why `if UserInput in excel` doesn't behave the same as `excel.loc[UserInput]`?

Comment: Bdw this is expected behavior, as you are trying to compare a value with a dataframe which would result in `False`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to accomplish? I had to build my own table to help visualize the process, but you should be able to accomplish what you asked with a little tweeking to your own data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Part_Number' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'Part_Name' : ['Name', 'Another Name', 'Third Name', 'Almost last name', 'last name']
})

user_input = int(input('Please enter part number'))

if user_input in df['Part_Number'].tolist():
    print(df.loc[df['Part_Number'] == user_input])
else:
    print('part number does not exist')
```

Comment: A minor tweek to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55872494/2986344 would be good too.

Comment: There are so many options out there! So cool thanks for the post =)