# I am unable to match a user input date with dates in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I am attempting to isolate the rows in a dataframe where dates match a user inputted date. Here is the full code with an included dataframe. Why doesn't it return my row?

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame({"Day": pd.to_datetime("2022-10-26"), "y": 5}, index=[0])
print(df)

get_year = input("Enter Year: ")
get_month = input("Enter Month: ")
get_day= input("Enter Day of Month: ")

inputdate = get_year+"-"+get_month+"-"+get_day
rundate1 = datetime.strptime(inputdate,'%Y-%m-%d')
rundate = (rundate1.date())
print(rundate)
x = df[df['Day']] == rundate
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`in Series`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319929/how-to-determine-whether-a-pandas-column-contains-a-particular-value) checks the index, you can do `in Series.tolist()` or `Series.eq().any()`

```py
rundate = pd.to_datetime(inputdate)

if rundate in df["Day"].tolist():
    print("yes its in here")
# or
if df["Day"].eq(rundate).any():
    print("yes its in here")
```

Comment: thanks Ynjxsjmh, i saw where you were going and i tried it, but it made me realise i need to alter the question

Comment: So, I guess I am saying that I'm not there yet, I need to get the rows from the df