# How can I get the column based on given value of a pandas Dataframe faster?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df that looks like this:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 6 | Cell 8 | Cell 4 |
| Cell 2 | Cell 7 | Cell 9 | Nan |
| Cell 3 | Nan | Cell 10 | Nan |
| Cell 4 | Nan | Nan | Nan |
| Cell 5 | Nan | Nan | Nan |

I'm trying to build a function such as the entry is any value in the df, and the output is the column to which the value belongs to.

My ideia would be doing something like

`df[df == val].stack().index[0][1]`

It does work, but it is a little to slow after a loot of iterations.
If you people know any other, faster way to get the same result, it would be much apretiated.

The df I am working with isn't much larger than this one. it's shape is (21, 16), maybe if I store it like a dict or something it would be better.

Please, any input would be apretiated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine whether a Pandas Column contains a particular value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319929/how-to-determine-whether-a-pandas-column-contains-a-particular-value)

Comment: Not quite, but it helps a little. Thanks for the contribution.

Comment: What should happen if you search "Cell 4" ? Should it return Column A, Column D, or both ?

Comment: @ScottC I made a mistake while typing the cells in the example, but I will keep, because there are good solutions for multiple columns having the same data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for indices for rows and columns, then filter columns names with `next` with `iter` trick for first matched value, if not matched value get custom string - here `not exist`:

```
r, c = np.where(df.to_numpy() == val)

first_matched_col = next(iter(df.columns[c]), 'not exist')
```

Comparison in small data sample - it is 53 times faster like original solution:

```
In [138]: %%timeit
     ...: df[df == val].stack().index[0][1]
     ...: 
1.23 ms ± 88.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [139]: %%timeit 
     ...: r, c = np.where(df == val)
     ...: 
     ...: first_matched_col = next(iter(df.columns[c]), 'not exist')
     ...: 
128 µs ± 23.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [140]: %%timeit 
     ...: r, c = np.where(df.to_numpy() == val)
     ...: 
     ...: first_matched_col = next(iter(df.columns[c]), 'not exist')
     ...: 
     ...: 
23.1 µs ± 1.39 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

For matched all matched values use `join`:

```
r, c = np.where(df.to_numpy() == val)
all_matched_col = ','.join(df.columns[c])
```

Comment: This is 10 times faster than my Implementation, guess I should try using more np instead of pandas when possible. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @RuanCarloWeiersBritzke - Faster solution working well in real data?

Answer (score 2):

There is another alternative, but is not as quick as the solution provided by jezrael. 
You can use the [df.eq()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) function in combination with the **any()** function to find the columns that contain the value. This function should return **True** for those columns that contain the value. You can then filter to select only those columns.

Here is an example of how that would work:

#### Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Column A': ['Cell 1', 'Cell 2', 'Cell 3', 'Cell 4', 'Cell 5'],
    'Column B': ['Cell 6', 'Cell 7',  None, None, None],
    'Column C': ['Cell 8', 'Cell 9', 'Cell 10', None, None],
    'Column D': ['Cell 4', None, None, None, None]
})

def get_Columns(df, val):
    columns = df.eq(val).any()
    result = list(columns[columns==True].index)
    return result
    
x = get_Columns(df, 'Cell 4')
print(x)
```

#### Output:

```
['Column A', 'Column D']
```

Comment: Not as fast, but well done aswell, might have uses for this later, thank you!